# How can I integrate Stripe Connect and Checkout products

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am using Stripe Checkout on my web application but now I would like to move to Stripe Connect since I have to support split payments to different stripe accounts. Before with Checkout was enough because all the funds went to my account and then I managed them accordingly but now some payments should have to be split and go to the Customer Stripe account and my stripe account as well.

So, I would like to still use the amazing Stripe Checkout Pop-up but I need to integrate it with the Stripe Connect API behind the scene. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) is only used to collect and tokenize the customer's payment information.

What you do with the token in your server-side code is up to you. You can use the token to create charges with [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect), either [directly](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges) or [through the platform](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges). Tokens created with a platform's publishable key can be used on the platform's account itself but also on any account that's connected to the platform.

If you have further questions, I recommend you reach out directly to Stripe's support at https://support.stripe.com/email and explain your business model and desired flow of funds so we can give you advice that's tailored to your needs.

Comment: Where? All the examples seem to be talking about the platform or the connected account, I can't find any example like "Use this platform key, this connected account ID and this token in this call to chard the token card and transfer it to the connected account"

Comment: this is an old thread, but for anyone like me looking to use checkout with Connect, see https://stripe.com/docs/connect/creating-a-payments-page